# Why can't I allocate bits of RAM?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, memory-alignment

I've heard that (most) Operating Systems require programs to allocate memory in byte chunks, I. E: a boolean value must be a byte wide when a single bit would do. Is there a particular reason why you can't allocate a bit?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about operating system design and not about a program that isn't working.

Comment: (And technically it is possible to allocate a single bit, but the overhead for an allocation is usually eight bytes or more, so allocating a single bit would be rather inefficient. If you look closely, most operating systems don't let you allocate a single byte either. The minimum is usually around eight or sixteen bytes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest unit of addressable memory is a byte. It is physically not possible for the CPU to load a single bit of memory.

Comment: Sorry if this is getting progressively off-topic, but why is it designed that way?